# Vim use 'a' like 'r'

Tags: vim

Is there a way to insert a single character like when r is used, but to append it after the cursor like when a is used (and return to command mode)?

e.g.

```
Some t[e]xt  " cursor on e (in command mode)
Some te[x]t  " input command I'm looking for, cursor on x and in insert mode
Some te[s]t  " type s and go back to command mode
```

Comment: What's the problem with just using `lr`?!

Comment: your `command mode == normal mode` ? or it means `command-line mode` ??

Comment: I just started using vim so I'm not sure about terminology. Yes I'm referring to normal mode (the mode in which you can execute commands like a and r from).

Comment: Hi Ingo. No problem with using lr... it's just that the reason I'm taking the trouble to learn vim is because I can customize it. Obviously, there should be a way to do something so simple. I'm just trying to learn how to tweak things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_a_single_character

Comment: Thx Hlopik, that was very similar to what I was looking for. Just needed to change it to :nmap <Space> a <Esc>r

Comment: @justin Even better: `:nmap <Space> lr`

Comment: Hi Lorkenpeist. That would be nice to have too (if I had enough keys to bind to :P). e.g. of what I wanted: consider "somefunctionname(Arg])", and you want to add "[" after "somefunctionname(". You do f( to go to "(" and just press a single character to insert "[" and return to normal mode. So a <Esc>r does the trick. lr would replace "A" in "Arg". Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another interesting way it could be done. Unlike other solutions, this one actually lets you type the character in insert mode and automatically reverts back to normal mode:

```
fun! s:InsertSingle()
  aug insertSingle
    au CursorMovedI * stopinsert | au! insertSingle
  aug END
  return 'a'
endf

nnoremap <expr> <space> <SID>InsertSingle()
```

Comment: Hi Daan. Interesting, thanks :)
Still I prefer the `:nmap <Space> a <Esc>r` for 2 reasons. It's simpler (even someone not fluent in scripting vim can understand it). Also, you can use `.` to repeat the whole operation. I tried using `.` with this approach and it just repeated the `r` part.
Still, it's nice to see you can get the job done in so many different ways. Cheers.